# How to make supercell of partial occupancies for DFT?

Tags: density-functional-theory

In the case of partial occupancies (for example, this [CIF](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/1009065.html)), a supercell should be made for DFT calculations. However, numerous supercells can be built from a lattice (in the above example, 200 different supercells).

**Which supercell should be used for the DFT calculations?**

Many DFT works (if not most) are based on partial occupancies (e.g., dopants). How is a typical supercell chosen for the DFT calculation?